# Problema con cin.ignore y getline al usar GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c++

Hola estoy haciendo un menú que se controla con las flechas del teclado y el enter usando [GetAsyncKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) y todo va bien, hasta el momento que ingreso los datos de un vendedor, el código es el siguiente:

```
void alta_vendedor(){
    system("cls");
    string app,apm,nom,rfc;
    char a;
    nuevo_vendedor aux;

    cout<<"\t\tAPELLIDO PATERNO DEL VENDEDOR"<<endl;
    getline(cin,app);
    cout<<"\t\tAPELLIDO MATERNO DEL VENDEDOR"<<endl;
    getline(cin,apm);
    cout<<"\t\t\tNOMBRE DEL VENDEDOR"<<endl;
    getline(cin,nom);
    cout<<"\t\t\tRFC DEL VENDEDOR"<<endl;
    getline(cin,rfc);

    menu_vendedor(1);
```

}

No pongo `cin.ignore()` en esa función porque cuando valido que se ingrese un enter lo pongo.

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)){
    cin.ignore();
    Sleep(300);
    if(op==1)   alta_vendedor();
    if(op==3)   control_menu();
}
```

Ahora bien el error radica al momento de terminar de ingresar los datos y volver al menú que se controla con el teclado, pues no puedo usar ningún botón hasta no dar un enter (se pone a leer datos del teclado como si estuviera en un `cin` o un `getline`).

pero al dar un enter hace que el menu lo reconozca y entre a una opcion sin que yo quiera, ya intente poner `cin.ignore` en varias partes y no se soluciona, tambien intente con `cin.clear` pero parece que esto no afecta en el codigo, espero darme a entender, llevo horas queriendo solucionar esto pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, gracias.